# Task not serializable - Java 1.8 and Spark 2.1.1

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a problem with Java 8 and Spark 2.1.1

I have a (valid) regular expression saved in a variable called "pattern". When I try to use this variable to filter the content loaded from a text file, a SparkException is thrown: Task not serializable. Can anyone help me? Here is the code:

```
  JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile(path);
  JavaRDD<String> filtered = lines.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(String v1) throws Exception {
            return v1.contains(pattern);
        }
    });
```

And here is the error stack

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2101)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(RDD.scala:387)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(RDD.scala:386)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.filter(RDD.scala:386)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.filter(JavaRDD.scala:78)
at FileReader.filteredRDD(FileReader.java:47)
at FileReader.main(FileReader.java:68)

Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: FileReader
Serialization stack:
- object not serializable (class: FileReader, value: FileReader@6107165)
- field (class: FileReader$1, name: this$0, type: class FileReader)
- object (class FileReader$1, FileReader$1@7c447c76)
- field (class: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD$$anonfun$filter$1, name: f$1, type: interface org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function)
- object (class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD$$anonfun$filter$1, <function1>)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
```

Comment: This piece of code is not complete, you are missing code that produces this error. Please provide a small but fully (dis-)functioning piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the report generated by spark for non-serializability

```
 - object not serializable (class: FileReader, 
   value: FileReader@6107165)
 - field (class: FileReader$1, name: this$0, type: 
         class FileReader)
 - object (class FileReader$1, 
           FileReader$1@7c447c76)
```

suggests the `FileReader` in the class where the closure is is non serializable. It happens when spark is not able to serialize only the method. Spark sees that and since methods cannot be serialized on their own, Spark tries to serialize the whole class.

In your code the variable `pattern` I presume is a class variable. This is causing the problem. Spark is unsure how to serialize the `pattern` without serializing the whole class.

> Try passing the pattern as a local variable to the closure and that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your class - serializable